# Azure Devops self hosted agent using old environment variables

Tags: azure-devops, azure-identity

I have a self hosted agent.  The service relies on [DefaultAzureCredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme#environment-variables) to use environment variables to connect to a Azure Key Vault. I rotated AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET and after remoting into the agent machine, I updated it as well. However after I ran a fresh build, the old value of that environment variable was used leading to connection failure. I have no specific cache task in the build pipeline.

Can someone help understand why an old value was used? Was it cached on the build agent or is it an issue with DefaultAzureCredentials implementation where credentials are cached?

Comment: Have you tried to restart the agent so that it picks up the changes in the environment variables?

Comment: Yes. Restart was done after updating the value.

Comment: I had similar issue with variable from ado library, I had to remove the variable from the library and then add it again, otherwise I have old value in pipeline. Restarting self hosted agent didn't help.